# KVM Bridged connection not forwarding ports?

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, centos6

Host and guest are both CentOS 6. Guest has an admin panel listening on port 15672 that I am unable to access from the outside.

From the guest, `curl localhost:15672` and `curl vm1:15672` give me the expected contents of the panel.

I can ping it

```
# ping vm1
PING vm1 (10.2.8.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.2.8.72: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
```

But not access the panel.

```
# curl vm1:15672
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I was following the instructions given [on this page](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking) and when I got to `brctl show`, my output was slightly different than what was shown but I'm not sure if it's relevant.

```
# brctl show
bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled  interfaces
br0          8000.842b2b78ff80  no           em1
                                             vnet0
virbr0       8000.5254000ea9ec  yes          virbr0-nic
```

And heres the xmldump from virsh

```
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>vm-queue</name>
  <uuid>f3d4a6e7-c4b7-97ea-7970-e7dbe0f6964c</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.6.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/var/kvm/images/vm-queue.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-1-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:6d:25:24'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c47,c569</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c47,c569</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

I'm sure you all need more information to go on than this but I don't understand this problem well enough I suppose.

What am I missing?

Comment: please add the `virsh dumpxml` output for the VM. did you make sure the ports weren't blocked on the host, btw?

Comment: xml dump added, i ran `netstat -tuplen` on the host machine and it doesn't show anything notable about port 15672 anywhere so I'm guessing thats good news.

Comment: ok, so you can ping the VM, that's nice, but where from? And is the port open in the VM's firewall?

Comment: There it is. Disabling the firewall on the guest VM allowed me to access the panel. I'm going to look into properly configuring iptables. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: sure. I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being the guest firewall blocking the application port, and not kvm or bridging related